# Is it possible to transfer media from Catalina to an iPod Nano?

Tags: catalina, ipod-nano

I have been wanting to update to Catalina but have been waiting. One of my biggest concerns is being able to transfer music to my iPod Nano. Is it still possible to import media from Catalina to the iPod Nano?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, all models of iPod sync will still sync with your Mac after you upgrade to macOS Catalina. Syncing is done in Finder instead of iTunes in the new OS.

Comment: I read the same thing in all of Apples online help docs, but I was able to sync iPod classic with Apple Music much better in fact. I could never get it working through Finder.